Why Java CPU usage show different inside node vs portal?
I am trying to  find out answer to that problem. Cluster has 5 nodes (on autoscaling mode), nodes are 8CPU, 64G RAM.
When I get inside 2 nodes I see 100% CPU taken by java process (java is taking only 2CPUs - why? - no additional config has been done); but when I look on Azure portal statistics I can only see ~27% or so CPU capacity.
Additional question: Can I somehow force Java to use more than 2 CPUs?
I have setup for G1GC with parameters:
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 heap=16G

I use Helm to deploy pods on cluster.



Two out of eight is one quarter or 25% … the difference to 27% is just the basic load on the other six CPUs.

ok, but I do not quite get you explanation. Where is this 100% load hidden than? It's loading those 2CPUs? Is there a way to increase no of CPUs load for java or is it automatic adjustment?

You said you see Java using 100% on two out of eight cores for the nodes you looked at, and that Java was only running on those two cores. Two out of eight is 25%. Or different: with 8 cores, you have a total CPU power of 4000 units (500 per core). Java is using 1000 of that, unfortunately unevenly distributed. Azure tells you correctly that 25% of that CPU power for the given node is utilized.
